# Possible Permutations for Source and Destination Lat/Long

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server called #Places1
[image]

A->B

C->D

E->F
I am trying to get all the possible permutations for this table but the Origin has to be IN before the Destination.

The issue is that I am generating some destination without the Origin. Can you please guide/help me to find a solution.

```
create table #places1
(

idgeneric int identity(1,1)

, id AS cast(CONCAT('0',cast(idgeneric as varchar(10))) as nvarchar(max))

, CatCode as cast(char(64+idgeneric) as nvarchar(max))

,OB_FREIGHT_ORDER_ID bigint

, lat decimal(9,6)

, long decimal(9,6)

, source nvarchar(max))

insert into #places1(OB_FREIGHT_ORDER_ID, lat, long, source)

select 25, 40.066863, -76.776681, 'Origin'

union all
select 25, 41.671810, -72.834214, 'Destination'

union all
select 26, 40.140015,-74.191128, 'Origin'

union all
select 26,41.738134, -72.198242, 'Destination'

union all
select 35, 41.488488,-74.234148, 'Origin'

union all
select 35,40.818434, -73.883721, 'Destination'

select * from #places1
```

Below the code that I have so far

```
Declare @counter int
Select  @counter = COUNT(*)
from    #places1;

DECLARE @Terminus TABLE (OD INT, node nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @Terminus

SELECT 1, id 
FROM (
      SELECT id FROM #places1 
      where source = 'origin'      

  EXCEPT 

      SELECT id 
      FROM #places1
      where source = 'Destination') x
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, id 
FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM #places1 
        where source = 'Destination'
EXCEPT 
        SELECT id 
        FROM #places1
        where source = 'origin') x


;With Permutations (permutation, IDs, source, Depth, count_origin,     count_destination)
as
(
Select c.CatCode
,c.ID + ';'
, cast(source as nvarchar(max))
--,lat
--,long
--,lat
--,long
--,parent
,Depth = 1
,case when source = 'Origin' then 1 else 0 end 
,case when source = 'Destination' then 1 else 0 end 
From #places1 c
WHERE id IN (SELECT node FROM @Terminus WHERE OD = 1)

union all

SELECT permutation + c.CatCode
,IDs + c.ID + ';' as IDs
,cast(p.source + '->'+ c.source as nvarchar(max)) as source
--,c.lat
--,c.long
--,p.d_lat
--,p.d_long
--,p.parent
,Depth = Depth + 1
,count_origin + case when c.source = 'Origin' then 1 else 0 end 
,count_destination + case when c.source = 'Destination' then 1 else 0 end 
FROM Permutations p
INNER JOIN #places1 c 
ON IDs not like '%' + ID + ';%'         
where (count_destination + case when c.source = 'Destination'      then     1 else 0 end <= count_origin + case when c.source = 'Origin' then 1 else 0 end ))

Select distinct *
from Permutations
where depth = @counter
```

see result issue..06 shouldn't be generated without its origin 05

[image: see result issue..06 shouldn't be generated without its origin 05]

Comment: Are you attempting the Traveling Salesman Problem?

Comment: Mine doesn't need to return to the origin city so I don't think so.

Comment: Fair enough.  Even then the numbers can get astronomical.  Just curious.  How many locations are you considering?

Comment: A max of 5 location. I am trying to make it work for 3 and go from there.